# iPod Controls in Lockscreen for own App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

How can I use the Lock Screen iPod Controls for my own App?

I tried MPNowPlayingInfoCenter, but if I set the information it won't be displayed anywhere; Not on the lock-screen and not in airplay on AppleTV.

I use the AVPlayer to play my audio files.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Take a look at the [Remote Control of Multimedia](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/RemoteControl/RemoteControl.html) documentation.

Here’s how to listen for remote control events in a `UIViewController` subclass. First, make your controller participate in the responder chain, otherwise the events will be forwarded to the app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder
{
    return YES;
}
```

Where appropriate, tell the application to start receiving events and make your controller the first responder:

```
// maybe not the best place but it works as an example
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Then respond to them:

```
- (void) remoteControlReceivedWithEvent: (UIEvent *) receivedEvent {

    if (receivedEvent.type == UIEventTypeRemoteControl) {

        switch (receivedEvent.subtype) {

            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlTogglePlayPause:
                [self playOrStop: nil];
                break;

            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlPreviousTrack:
                [self previousTrack: nil];
                break;

            case UIEventSubtypeRemoteControlNextTrack:
                [self nextTrack: nil];
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what's not obvious here is that viewDidAppear should be declared in the viewController, whilst remoteControlReceivedWithEvent should be declared in the app delegate.

Comment: That’s not necessary, but was true in my previous example. I forgot to convey a subtle point from the documentation: `UIViewController` can participate in the responder chain, but only after overriding `-(BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder` to return `YES`. See my edit.